# Using sympy.integrate on a function that involves int()

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to integrate functions in Python. scipy.integrate.quad seems to work ok; but just be sure I'd like to check the results against other integration code. It was suggested that I try sympy.integrate. Now the code for the functions I want to integrate contains int(), which I use to convert floats into ints. This is ok for quad, but not for sympy.integrate.

Here's a simple example that reproduces the error:

```
import sympy

def f(x):
    return sympy.exp(int(x))

sympy.symbols('x')
print(sympy.integrate(f(x),(x,0,2)))
```

This yields the error: `TypeError: can't convert symbols to int`

So is there a way to integrate functions that involve int() with scipy.integrate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `integrate` `f` must be a SymPy symbolic function which disallows your particular use of `int`. `int(x)` where `x` is a `Symbol` will always yield a type error however you could represent this symbolically using the `floor` function:

```
def f(x):
    return sympy.exp(sympy.floor(x))
```

However, using `floor` may defeat some of the purpose of using SymPy in the first place because it will probably prevent discovery of an analytic solution as the following python session demonstrates:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols("x")
>>> integrate(exp(floor(x)), (x, 0, 2))  # use of floor prevents evaluated result
Integral(exp(floor(x)), (x, 0, 2))
```

Though you can use the `evalf` method to compute a numeric result (which is ultimately performed by mpmath):

```
>>> integrate(exp(floor(x)), (x, 0, 2)).evalf()
3.7
```

(<s>perhaps this result suggests sympy could better handle this integral?</s> Wolfram Alpha computes this as `1 + e = 3.71828...` so I suppose there is at least a floating point precision bug here too - see comment re `ceiling`)

In any case, I don't know if you consider that an appropriate result considering the version of `f` without `floor`:

```
>>> integrate(exp(x), (x, 0, 2))
-1 + exp(2)
>>> _.evalf()
6.38905609893065
```

Comment: Curiously `integrate(exp(ceiling(x)), (x, 0, 2)).evalf(100)` seems to result in at least a precision bug in SymPy's floating point evaluation (it prints as `1.e+1`)

Comment: really just a definite integral of a piecewise constant function so sympy should be able to compute an exact result - looks like there are a few open issues https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12234 https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8480